# How can I filter/search multiple subarrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am working on a search function for a parent child structure with locations (city,suburb,street).
I want to search for a street name and get the results but keeping the structure.

The array structure is like this:

```
const cities = [
  {
    name: 'city1', sublocations: [
      {
        name: 'suburb1', sublocations: [
          {name: 'street1'},
          {name: 'street2'},
          {name: 'street3'},
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'suburb2', sublocations: [
          {name: 'street1'},
          {name: 'street2'},
          {name: 'street3'},
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

When I search for *street1* for example I want to get this:

```
const cities = [
  {
    name: 'city1', sublocations: [
      {
        name: 'suburb1', sublocations: [
          {name: 'street1'},
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'suburb2', sublocations: [
          {name: 'street1'},
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I tried it with the array.filter function but it overwrites the data and when I remove the search string the rest of the array doesn't come back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this snippet should do the trick :

```js
var cities = [
 {name :'city1', sublocations:[
     {name :'suburb1', sublocations:[
         {name :'street1'},
         {name :'street2'}, 
          {name :'street3'}, 
     ]},
     {name :'suburb2', sublocations:[
         {name :'street1'},
         {name :'street2'}, 
         {name :'street3'}, 
     ]}
 ]}
];
let findStreet = function(streetName) {
  return cities.map(city=>
    ({...city, sublocations:city.sublocations.map(suburb=>
      ({...suburb, sublocations:suburb.sublocations.filter(
          street=>street.name===streetName
        )
      })
    )})
  )
}
console.log(findStreet("street1"));
```

Comment: Thank you! The search function now works exactly as I want.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a bit more flexibility you could generalize the *location type* by adding a `type` key, e.g.:

```
{ type: 'city', name: 'city1', locations: [] }
```

And then use a recursive filter function to make a decision for each node in the tree, e.g.:

```
const filterTree = (nodes, childrenKey, selector) => {
  return nodes.filter(selector).map(node => {
    return node.hasOwnProperty(childrenKey)
      ? {...node, [childrenKey]: filterTree(node[childrenKey], childrenKey, selector)}
      : node;
  });
};
```

Example:

```js
const locations = [
  {
    type: 'city', name: 'city1', locations: [
      {
        type: 'suburb', name: 'suburb1', locations: [
          {
            type: 'street',
            name: 'street1'
          },
          {
            type: 'street',
            name: 'street2'
          },
          {
            type: 'street',
            name: 'street3'
          },
        ]
      }, {
        type: 'suburb', name: 'suburb2', locations: [
          {
            type: 'street',
            name: 'street1'
          },
          {
            type: 'street',
            name: 'street2'
          },
          {
            type: 'street',
            name: 'street3'
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const filterTree = (nodes, childrenKey, selector) => {
  return nodes.filter(selector).map(node => {
    return node.hasOwnProperty(childrenKey)
      ? {...node, [childrenKey]: filterTree(node[childrenKey], childrenKey, selector)}
      : node;
  });
};

// example
const filtered = filterTree(locations, 'locations', ({type, name}) => {
  return type === 'city'                           // allow all cities 
      || (type === 'suburb' && name === 'suburb2') // but only specific suburbs
      || (type === 'street' && name === 'street2') // and streets;
});

console.log(filtered);
```